# C# WPF moving rectangle when key is pressed without short delay

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm moving a rectangle when holding the left, right, up or downkey in a specific direction.

When I hold down the key the rectangle stops for a short time. But what do I have to do if I want it to move freely without that short stopping?

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window KeyDown="myTestKey">
<Canvas>
    <Rectangle Name="Movement" Canvas.Top="50" Canvas.Left="50" Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Aquamarine"/>
</Canvas>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void myTestKey(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Left) Canvas.SetLeft(Movement, Canvas.GetLeft(Movement) - 1);
        if (e.Key == Key.Up) Canvas.SetTop(Movement, Canvas.GetTop(Movement) - 1);
        if (e.Key == Key.Down) Canvas.SetTop(Movement, Canvas.GetTop(Movement) + 1);
        if (e.Key == Key.Right) Canvas.SetLeft(Movement, Canvas.GetLeft(Movement) + 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform the movement in a `Timer` event, and enable the movement in `KeyDown` event and disable the movement in a `KeyUp` event

Answer (score 0):

The key delay setting that controls the delay between the initial key press and the subsequent detection of continuous repetition is a Windows setting. See https://superuser.com/questions/388160/keyboard-repeat-rate-repeat-delay-values-in-win7 for a discussion.